# NodeJS from localhost to live server: What folders should i upload to server?

Tags: node.js

I have installed npm and node on localhost using command terminal. I can view my nodejs app after entering command `npm start` in the command prompt and going to address `http://localhost:3000`. Now, I have to upload this setup to live server. What folders do I need to move to the server and what commands should i execute to make it work on live server?

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: on localhost, ubuntu. On live server, I m not sure but it's some flavour of linux i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

except node_modules you have to upload the necessary files and folders. In server try `npm install`.

Comment: what other commands do i need to run after `npm install`. e.g. to fetch and install packages specified in package.json etc.

Comment: npm install fetch all the npm library. so you do not need to run any command.

Comment: but how will it install the project specific packages then?

Comment: using package.json file. you have to write all dependencies in package.json file.

Comment: Thanks Kundu. I did as you told. Moved all files and folders except node_modules to the server using filezilla. Then cd to the project root directory and ran `npm install`. that fetched and installed all the required packages. Then, i executed `npm start` and I was able to view my site on live url. Thanks :)